# How Do I auto size the content I'm exporting to WORD using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I wrote a VBA code that will export my contents to a word document, however once the command is executed, the contents are oversized in the word document. Could anyone please look at my code and offer help?

```
Sub export_excel_to_word()

Set obj = CreateObject("Word.Application")
obj.Visible = True
Set newObj = obj.Documents.Add
ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Copy
newObj.Range.Paste
Application.CutCopyMode = False
obj.Activate
newObj.SaveAs Filename:=Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\" & ActiveSheet.Name
```

End Sub

Answer (score 0):

After you paste the cells (`newObj.Range.Paste`) type this:

```
newObj.Range.Tables(1).Range.ParagraphFormat.SpaceAfter = 0
newObj.Range.Tables(1).AutoFitBehavior wdAutoFitWindow
```

It wil make the cells "Normal" size.

Comment: What I found out was the document needs to be in Landscape form for the contents to fit within the page, what's the code to automatically set it to landscape mode after the command has been executed?

Comment: I tried doing the following but it still does not print it in Landscape mode Sub export_excel_to_word()

    Set obj = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    obj.Visible = True
    Set newObj = obj.Documents.Add
    ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Copy
    newObj.Range.Paste
    ActiveSheet.PageSetup.Orientation = xlLandscape
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    obj.Activate
    newObj.SaveAs Filename:=Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\" & ActiveSheet.Name
    
End Sub

Comment: I'm sorry but I honestly don't know the code for landscape mode. You might have to ask someone more experienced or look it up on the web. Or try it with Macro recording.